# assimp: Loading "mTransformation" and "mOffsetMatrix" the right way. How to load skeletal animation from assimp?

Tags: c++, assimp, skeletal-animation

I am currently trying to load a skeletal animation from a collada file (.dae).
But there seems to be a bug in my code which I can not find myself.

The bug visualizes in not showing the last child's of the hierarchy at all.
They are loaded but transformed in a way they disappear.

I try to give as dense code spinets as needed to understand what I am doing.
If you need more context please request it!

The code I am using for loading the bone transformations:

Where `bone_map` is the map that translate from assimp joint name to my joint array.

```cpp
mesh.joint_local_transformations = std::make_unique<glm::mat4[]>(ai_mesh->mNumBones);
mesh.joint_global_inverse_transformations = std::make_unique<glm::mat4[]>(ai_mesh->mNumBones);
mesh.joint_count = ai_mesh->mNumBones;

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ai_mesh->mNumBones; ++i)
{
  const auto *joint = ai_mesh->mBones[i];
  if (bone_map.contains(joint->mName.data))
  {
    const auto joint_index = bone_map.at(joint->mName.data);

    auto joint_transformation_invert = fromAiMat4(joint->mOffsetMatrix);

    const auto *node = find_node(joint->mName, ai_scene);
    auto joint_transformation = fromAiMat4(node->mTransformation);

    mesh.joint_global_inverse_transformations[joint_index] = joint_transformation_invert;
    mesh.joint_local_transformations[joint_index] = joint_transformation;
  }
}
```

The code I am using for loading animation transformations:

```
anim.joint_transformations = std::make_unique<Animation::JointTransformation[]>(anim.key_frame_count * anim.joint_count);

for (size_t i = 0; i < anim.key_frame_count; ++i)
{
  for (size_t j = 0; j < ai_anim->mNumChannels; ++j)
  {
    if (bone_map.contains(ai_anim->mChannels[j]->mNodeName.data))
    {
      const auto bone_index = bone_map.at(ai_anim->mChannels[j]->mNodeName.data);

      const auto r = ai_anim->mChannels[j]->mRotationKeys[i].mValue;
      const auto s = ai_anim->mChannels[j]->mScalingKeys[i].mValue;
      const auto p = ai_anim->mChannels[j]->mPositionKeys[i].mValue;

      Animation::JointTransformation t{};
      t.rotation = {r.w, r.x, r.y, r.z};
      t.scale = {s.x, s.y, s.z};
      t.translation = {p.x, p.y, p.z};
      anim.joint_transformations[anim.joint_count * i + bone_index] = t;
    }
  }
}
```

The code I am using to animate:

Where `i` is the current key frame index and `j` is the current joint index.

Where `joints` is the array of transformations that is passed into the shader. (the result)

Notice that a parent has always a lower index than is child. Therefor a parent is always processed first.

```cpp
const auto *f0 = &(anim->joint_transformations[(i - 1) * anim->joint_count]);
const auto *f1 = &(anim->joint_transformations[(i - 0) * anim->joint_count]);

joints[0] = Animation::mix(f0[0], f1[0], current_time);

for (uint32_t j = 1; j < mesh->joint_count; ++j)
{
    const auto &parent = joints[mesh->joint_parent_indices[j]];
    joints[j] = parent * Animation::mix(f0[j], f1[j], current_time);
}

for (uint32_t j = 0; j < mesh->joint_count; ++j)
{
    joints[j] = joints[j] * mesh->joint_global_inverse_transformations[j];
}
```

The data structure used (probably not relevant for the problem):

```cpp
struct Mesh
{
    std::unique_ptr<glm::vec3[]> vertices;
    std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[]> indices;
    std::unique_ptr<glm::vec3[]> normals;
    std::unique_ptr<glm::vec2[]> tex_coords;

    uint32_t vertex_count;
    uint32_t indices_count;
};

struct AnimatedMesh
        : public Mesh
{
    std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[]> joint_indices;
    std::unique_ptr<float[]> joint_weights;

    std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4[]> joint_local_transformations;
    std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4[]> joint_global_inverse_transformations;
    std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[]> joint_parent_indices;

    uint32_t joint_count;
    uint32_t joints_per_vertex = 3;
};

struct Animation
{
    struct JointTransformation
    {
        glm::vec3 translation;
        glm::quat rotation;
        glm::vec3 scale;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<JointTransformation[]> joint_transformations;
    std::unique_ptr<float[]> joint_timestamps;

    uint32_t joint_count;
    uint32_t key_frame_count;

    static glm::mat4 mix (const JointTransformation &t0, const JointTransformation &t1, float delta)
    {
        const auto t = glm::translate(glm::identity<glm::mat4>(), glm::mix(t0.translation, t1.translation, delta));
        const auto r = glm::toMat4(glm::slerp(t0.rotation, t1.rotation, delta));
        const auto s = glm::scale(glm::identity<glm::mat4>(), glm::mix(t0.scale, t1.scale, delta));
        return t * r * s;
    }
};
```

Thanks to everyone who tries to help!